# Any way to manually indicate element of a MutableArray# safe to GC?

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, ghc

In my application I'm working with `MutableArray`s (via the [primitive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Primitive-Array.html#t%3aMutableArray) package) shared across threads. I know when individual elements are no longer used and I'd like some way (`unsafeMarkGarbage` or something) to indicate to the runtime that they can be collected. At least I'd like to experiment with that if such a function or equivalent technique exists.

**EDIT, to add a bit more detail**: I've got a conceptual "infinite tape" implemented as a linked list of short `MutableArray` segments, something like:

```
data Seg a = Seg (MutableArray a) (IORef (Maybe (Seg a)))
```

I access the tape using a concurrent counter and always know when an element of the tape will no longer be accessed. In certain cases when a thread is descheduled it's possible that entire array segments (both the array and its elements) which could have been GC'd will stick around as their references will persist.

An ideal solution would avoid an additional write (maybe that's silly), avoid another layer of indirection in the array, and allow entire `MutableArray`s to be collected when all their elements expire.

`Weak` references do seem to be the most promising sort of mechanism I've seen, but I can't yet see how they can help me here.

Comment: Since you don't care about the value of the cell of the array, can you assign some other small value to the cell so that the garbage collector no longer reaches the structure you'd like to have eligible for garbage collection? For example, in an array of `Maybe a` you could write `Nothing`, or in an array of `[a]` you could write `[]`, etc.

Comment: I can't give really good advice, since I've never used them before; but you might want to look into [weak pointers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/System-Mem-Weak.html). (If that turns out to be valuable, you should add what you did with them as an answer!)

Comment: Thanks, updated the question with more details.

Comment: We've previously suggested weak pointers for your problem, but that depends on how your data structure will be traversed.  Will all threads traverse it in a streaming fashion starting at the front? In that case garbage collection will probably take care of reclaiming the memory. If it's the case that some threads extend the structure but when they're done you wish to remove the stuff they added? In that case I think weak pointers could work really well. Just replace the `IORef (Maybe _)` with `Weak`.
But as I said,  it all comes down to the access pattern which solution will work best for you.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you store `undefined` in the positions that you would like to garbage collect.

Comment: Thanks. This might be the best I can do for now. I meant to include that an ideal solution would also allow the array itself to be collected when all elements are seen as garbage (and also avoiding an extra write would be nice).

Comment: It sounds like weak pointers are your friends here. But maybe if you explained on a higher level what it is that you're trying to achieve we might be able to give you better advice.

Comment: Updated the question with more details.